# sqlite3 command line - how to set mode and import in one step

Tags: command-line, csv, sqlite

I need to be able to do this via command line in one step:

```
lab-1:/etc/scripts# sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .mode csv ;
sqlite> .import /tmp/test.csv users
sqlite> select * from users;
John,Doe,au,0,"",1,5555,91647fs59222,audio
sqlite> .quit
```

I've tried the following:

```
 lab-1:/etc/scripts# sqlite3 test.db ".mode csv ; .import /tmp/deleteme.csv users"
```

and

```
 lab-1:/etc/scripts# sqlite3 test.db ".mode csv .import /tmp/deleteme.csv users"
```

I don't get errors but I also don't end up with any data in the users table.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLite meta commands are not terminated by `;` but by newline.  Therefore, you will have to provide the commands in some other way so that newlines are inserted in the correct places.

Here's a few examples, of which I would probably use the first one (because it's readable).

1. Use a here-document:

   ```
   sqlite3 testdb <<END_COMMANDS
   .mode csv
   .import /tmp/deleteme.csv users
   END_COMMANDS
   ```
2. Format the commands with `printf`:

   ```
   printf '.mode csv\n.import /tmp/deleteme.csv users\n' | sqlite3 test.db
   ```
3. Use a here-string with C-escapes (in shells that supports it):

   ```
   sqlite3 test.db <<<$'.mode csv\n.import /tmp/deleteme.csv users\n'
   ```